GeoServer, cannot login
I have GeoServer Version 2.24.1 on Windows Server 2019 with Jetty.
GeoServer data directory is on separate disc e, app is on c.
Suddenly I cannot login any more. I use GUI to work with this instance of GeoServer.
No one from my colleges could change the credentials, so they should be the same. I checked
"...\Geodata\Geoserver\security\usergroup\default\users.xml", where credentials should be stored and the file is couple of months old, so no changes to it in last days when something happened that is now preventing to log in.
I restarted GeoServer, it works fine, but I still cannot login.
Then I also tried to change
<user password="plain:test" name="admin" enabled="true"/> 

in "...Geodata\Geoserver\security\usergroup\default\users.xml" but after restarting GeoServer also login with "admin" and psw "test" is not successful.
After that I reinstalled GeoServer pointing to existing data directory, but still no luck with login. This is also logical somehow for me, because security folder (Geodata\Geoserver\security) on data directory is not changed during install.
I found on chatGPT that deleting complete "...\Geodata\Geoserver\security" directory would help, because GeoServer after restarting recreates it. I tried, GeoServer in fact creates a new one and then I can login with default user=admin and psw=geoserver, but "Layer preview" and "Layer Groups" report errors. I changed complete "...\Geodata\Geoserver\security" back to original and start GeoServer, which works fine again (all layers - more than 300), but login is still unsuccessful.
Here is my log:

Any idea what could be wrong or any other way how to reset password and not change geo data on data directory?

Something above GeoServer is broken, likely your Http engine or application server


jetty comes with win installation and there is nothing else on this server and nothing new


GeoServer is a placid and well behaved application and will never change your password "suddenly", so it must think you meant to do it. The most likely problem is that the disk with your configuration was not available or readable when it restarted so it decided that you were making a new install and generated (or reverted to) the default configuration, which effectively resets your password to geoserver so I would try that first. Then check where GeoServer thinks it's data directory is.
If that isn't the case then you (or one of your other users with the admin password) has changed the password and forgotten to tell you.
Finally, if you continue to be able to regain access you can reinstall and point your GeoServer at your existing data directory (provided you didn't leave it in the default install).
If all else fails you can break back in if you have the ability to log in to the server by following this answer.

Please take the [tour] to find out how this site works including the [edit] button to add details to your question

I did edit my question with all my notes done and I would be very happy to get an updated answer
